# Why CSS background property overrides previously defined instance?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I came across the following issue.

I have two HTML sections.
Within the first section, I have an `<p>` element defined.
The said `<p>` element comes after a `<div>` with a class called "text-box"
I have selected this `<p>` element within my stylesheet by calling in following manner.

```
    .text-box p {
                 margin: 10px 0 40px;
                 font-size: 14px;
                 color: #fff;
                }
```

Then there is a second section and in that there is a second `<p>` element. I have selected this `<p>` element in the following manner and applied relevant styling within my style sheet.

```
     p {
          color: #fff;
          font-size: 49px;
          font-weight: 300;
          line-height: 22px;
          padding: 10px;
          background: red;
      }
```

My question is, out of all CSS rules I have defined for the second `<p>` element, the background: red; rule gets applied to the first `<p>` element as well. I can not understand why it happens as none of the other rules I have applied are affecting the first `<p>` element but the background property. I am sure this is something very straightforward I am missing here. Can someone help me, please?

For a better understanding, the HTML and the CSS content are in the following codepen.

https://codepen.io/aroshjayamanne/pen/yLXvZPy

Answer (score 2):

All of your styles specified for `p` will be applied to all `p` elements except where overridden by specifications for `.text-box p` which is a more specific selector. For `.text-box p`, you have replaced the `font-size` specification from `p` but you do not have a `background` specified, so it uses the one you've specified for the more general `p`.

If you do not want a background for `.text-box p`, you can unset it with `background: unset;`.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with `p` will overlay all tags with `p`. But, for example, when you do `.mydiv p`, it will treat the `p` inside your `div` and give it a background.

HTML

```
<div class="mydiv"> <p>Hello</p> </div>
```

or

```
<p class="mytitle">Hi</p>
```

CSS

```
.mydiv p{
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

or

```
.mytitle{
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update** your second section paragraph tag style by selecting the parent class name **`course`** to **eliminate** any another paragraph outside this section from taking its properties as the following

```
.course p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 49px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```